# What is the role of weight neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I am new in Deep learning but i am unable to get the role of Weight in neural network(perceptron).
please help to explain with example.

Comment: accept an answer if it helps stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

The weight is a connection between two neurons.

You could think of it as the strenght of the connection between the two neurons.

For example if you connect a neuron to another with a weight, the higher the weight, the higher the activation is of the secound neuron.

Comment: Thanks allot brother... that means weight perform a big role between two neurons. and is it automatically taken or we need to take it manually?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Neural Network works mostly by applying non-linearity to a weighted sum.

In very simple words, A weighted sum is just a vector multiplied by a weight vector and their sum is taken.

Let's say, we have a vector a = [1, 2, 3]
Now, it could be an input to the network or maybe just some output of intermediate network.

Now, we have another weight vector w = [4, 2, -1]

We get the weighted sum by doing an element-wise multiplication -> SUM(a.*w) = SUM([1*4, 2*2, 3*-1]) = SUM([4, 4, -3]) = 4+4-3 = 5

Now, a very simple scenario, let's assume if our input is [1, 2, 3], our output should be +1 (positive class).

So, in MLP, we take a threshold, for our case, it could be 0, so as our output is 5, and 5 > threshold 0, so our output class = +1

Now, why we chose w = [4, 2, -1]. Well, we didn't, we trained our MLP on a dataset to learn this w, if it was [-4,-2,-1], our prediction would be wrong.

So, that's the weight vector in MLP and we learn it using an algorithm by SGD.

Every sklearn's transform's fit() just calculates the parameters (e.g. μ and σ in case of StandardScaler) and saves them as an internal objects state. Afterwards, you can call its transform() method to apply the transformation to a particular set of examples.

fit_transform() joins these two steps and is used for the initial fitting of parameters on the training set x, but it also returns a transformed x′. Internally, it just calls first fit() and then transform() on the same data.

So, fit_transform = fit + transform.
image source: Hacker Noon

Comment: Thanks you so much dear... and why we use fit and fit_transform? what is the difference between that?

Comment: @Dheerajkumar updated my answer, kindly accept it if it answers your question.